# Pass custom variable to block.html.twig

Tags: theming

I have a customer who requires the correct set of responsive classes for his block in a given theme depending on its position and count. In my `theme_preprocess_page(&$vars)` I can identify the blocks in this region and build up an array for each block using its plugin_id and save it to `$variables['highlighted']`.

In my **page.html.twig** I use `{{ highlighted }}` and the array shows up wonderfully. Because **block.html.twig** by default is set up to be looking for `{{ plugin_id }}` I expected that I can test if plugin_id is `in_array()` and add these classes to that instance of the block.

But `{{ highlighted }}` in **block.html.twig** returns null in this theme, suggesting that `$variables['page']` works for the page, but not block?
Twig has a way to pass off variables to an arbitrary twig file but I do not know how to do this in Drupal. For instance, my **page.html.twig** is using `{{ highlighted }}` to pull in these blocks from `$variables`.

**So my question is how does Drupal 8's adaptation the Twig source determine which variables are passed (plugin_id, content, attributes, id, etc) and how I can add mine?** I've looked through the twig.engine and searched the Twig source, but it's not clear to me which class controls what variables are passed to blocks?
My other avenue is to find a way to pass this array of classes to `theme_preprocess_block` but every attempt I made to try this ends up with `theme_preprocess_block` returning NULL for this array, suggesting that `preprocess_page()` and `preprocess_block()` are working separtely.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to preprocess the block instead of the page. Preprocessing pages will not pass a variable to the block. See [hook_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x). If you are needing to determine values based on how many times a block is rendered you can look into using [drupal_static](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7.x) to store variables that can be reused during the rendering process.

Drupal static example:

```
$first_row = &drupal_static('first_row');

if ($first_row == 2) {
  // I equal 2
}

// Since I am passed by reference I can alter and will keep my value.
$first_row++;
```

Comment: OK, reading drupal_static() sounds best because it survives render. It's not clear how to recall the static array in theme_preprocess_block. theme_preprocess_page invokes drupal_static_reset('processor_func'). Then gathers blocks in a region in a page and hands off to processor_func($blocks) which instantiates &drupal_static() and then builds up array of classes after verifying !isset('processor_func'). I don't see what variable I put in theme_preprocess_block() to get this array.

Comment: Your preprocess $variables parameter should be able to be edited and added to a value that you can use in the template $variables['my_new_value'] should be available for use in tht template.